# Interactive spreadsheet survey

Tags: microsoft-excel, survey, spreadsheet

I'm looking for an online survey platform which would allow participants to input information into a blank interactive online spreadsheet. 
The spreadsheet would be blank for each individual participant and I would then be able to export the collected data into a CSV file. Does something like this exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclosure: I work for PollUnit.**

I'm not sure I understood you right. By "blank" you mean a completely empty table without table header? If not [PollUnit](https://pollunit.com/en) might be something for you.

If you create a poll of type "Free Table", you can define columns. Your users fill in the rows.

CSV and Excel export is only possible in the payed accounts.

At https://pollunit.com/en/table you will find some examples.

Comment: Thank you very much! Poll Unit looks nice. What I mean by 'blank' is that I want each participant's information that they put into the table to be private. I want each person who uses the table to be able to add information to it but I don't want them to see each other's work. Only I would be able to see everything. Do you know of any platform that could help with that?

Comment: @Wavetree With PollUnit you can choose between different private settings. But this is also only possible in the payed accounts. It's in the Advanced step of the wizard. There you can choose "hide participants".

And another idea would be to use a survey tool which allows multiple questions. I am sure, most of these tools can export those questions in a table form.